# MarshalAs question in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, dllimport

I'm having trouble receiving data from an external dll routine. The dll is to read data from a mirco-controller chip.  This works fine in Delphi,and I'm trying to get it to work in C#.

Adr: Starting address
Len: Total length of the data being read

The function returns a TData array where the item with index 0 contains the starting
address and the item with index 1 contains the length of the data received. Following
items (index 2 and higher) contain the data received. If the Receive operation fails, the
length value returned in the array is set to zero

```
  [DllImport("dsio.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
  public static extern byte[] Receive(int Adr, int Len);

  private void BtnReceive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         byte[] Data = new byte[256];
         int Adr = 0x05;
         int Len = 8;

         Data = Receive(Adr, Len);
         txtBox2.Text = Data;
     }
```

Comment: Very unclear what this function returns.  Other than that it is not byte[].

Comment: Have you tried not using MarshalAs? Do you know if the dll is returning a C-style array or SafeArray?

Comment: Show C function prototype and code fragment calling this function in any language (better C).

Comment: Alex,  here is the original Delphi .pas code " type
  TData = array [0..255] of byte;  function Receive(Adr, Len: integer): TData; stdcall; external 'dsio.dll';  procedure TForm1.Button8Click(Sender: TObject);
var Data: TData;
    i: integer;
    s: string;
begin

for i:=0 to 255 do Data[i]:=0;
Data:=Receive($02,8);
if (Data[1]=0) then
  begin StatusBar1.SimpleText:='Failed'; exit; end;
s:='';
for i:=1 to 8 do
  s:=s+Chr(Data[i+1]);
Edit1.Text:=s;

end;

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is unnecessary to instantiate `new byte[256]` since you are setting `Data` to the return result of `Receive()`.

You should try removing the `[return: MarshalAs]` attribute to see if the default marshalling work.

If it does not work, [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx) indicates that [`SizeConst`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.sizeconst.aspx) and [`SizeParamIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.sizeparamindex.aspx) should also be set in the `MarshalAs` attribute declaration when using `UnmanagedType.LPArray`. I do not know whether you need to use one or both of those parameters (read the linked documentation and experiment). `SizeParamIndex`, if needed, will be `1` because the second argument is the length.

```
[return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 256, SizeParamIndex = 1 )]
```

*Addendum*: Since you declare `TData` as a type, that gives me an idea that using a `struct` in C# may also work, and it helps isolate the first 2 bytes if it does:

```
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
public struct TData {
    public byte StartAddress = 0;
    public byte Length = 0;
    public byte[] Data = new byte[ 254 ];
}
```

If you try to use this, I'm pretty sure you remove `return: MarshalAs` and default marshaling should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help I removed the `new byte[256]` and the `[return: MarshalAs]` attribute no change in the error at this line, `Data = Receive(Adr, Len)` "MarshalDirectiveException was unhandled"
"cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination" The Adr is a memory pointer, the Len is the length of data received.

Comment: Sorry, I left out the bit the mention of `LPArray`. What was meant was if you do need to use LPArray, try specifying `SizeConst` and `SizeParamIndex` of `MarshalAs` attribute.

Comment: Joel,  would you have an example of the LPArry, SizeConst, SizeParamIndex  structure?

Comment: There you go. Since I don't have the same thing or similar to test with, you're going to have to play around with these pieces a bit to see if something works.